# Printing an Arraylist in toString with new lines separating each entry

Tags: java, tostring

I have a toString that needs to print a lot of stuff, including an Arraylist which contains multiple entries. Those entries have to be separated by a new line. Here is the toString code that I am working with right now:

```
@Override
public String toString() // Displays the info for a class
{            
    return getCourseId() + "\n" + getCourseName() + "\n" + getCourseCode()
        + "\n" + "\n" + "Instructor" + "\n" + "-------------------------" 
        + "\n" + Instructor.toString() + "\n" + "\n" + "Student Roster" 
        + "\n" + "-------------------------" + "\n" + roster;
}
```

The roster does print, but all of the entries exist on the same line with brackets and commas.

My instructor insists that the toString be self-contained, so everything that I have in the toString currently has to stay there.

The roster prints like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() // Displays the info for a person in order
{
    return getPersonId() + "\t" + getLastName() + "\t" + getFirstName()
        + "\t" + getMajor() + "\t" + getGpa();
}
```

Currently, I get the output that looks like this:

```
10000
College Algebra
MATH 101

Instructor
-------------------------
X00009876   Jones   Jane    Associate Professor Mathematics

Student Roster
-------------------------
[X00000002  Smith   Sally   History         2.98, X00000003 Adams   Amanda                    Civil Engineering    3.7, X00000005  Turner  Thomas  Nursing         2.34]
```

But I would like it to look like this:

```
10000
College Algebra
MATH 101

Instructor
-------------------------
X00009876   Jones   Jane    Associate Professor Mathematics

Student Roster
-------------------------
X00000002   Smith   Sally   History         2.98
X00000003   Adams   Amanda     Civil Engineering    3.7
X00000005   Turner  Thomas  Nursing         2.34
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @dimo414, I think the OP has posted the question before to [Printing an Arraylist in toString with lines separating each entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625109/printing-an-arraylist-in-tostring-with-lines-separating-each-entry?rq=1). Is there some reason the solutions in that question were not helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Either use

```
roster.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
```

or

```
String.join("\n", roster)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for roster:

```
... + roster.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out my problem. I had to remove the return statement and put it at the end so I could put a for-each loop and print my Arraylist. Here's what the final code looked like:

```
@Override
public String toString() // Displays the info for a class
    {             

        System.out.print(getCourseId() + "\n" + getCourseName() + "\n" + getCourseCode()
            + "\n" + "\n" + "Instructor" + "\n" + "-------------------------" 
            + "\n" + Instructor.toString() + "\n" + "\n" + "Student Roster" 
            + "\n" + "-------------------------" + "\n");
                roster.stream().forEach((tmp) -> { // for each student, put 
                    System.out.println(tmp);       // them on a new line
    });

        return "";
    }
```